# What do these of-complements mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> One [this one is neither Andrew nor Stuart] of them seized the wood-backed board rubber from Miss Harvey’s vacated desk. He threw it. The rubber soared right across the room and crashed into the clock on the back wall, which plummeted to the ground and shattered: 
>   . . . . . .
>   ‘That’s enough,’ said Cubby. ‘If I hear any more noise like that from this class, I’ll put the whole lot of you in detention. Do you understand? All of you.’ 
>   He shut the door on their laughter. 
>   ‘You heard the deputy headmaster!’ cried Miss Harvey, scurrying to the front of the room. ‘Be quiet! I want quiet! You – Andrew – and you, Stuart – you can clear up that mess! Pick up all those bits of clock!’ 
>   They set up a routine cry **of injustice** at this, supported shrilly by a couple of the girls.
>   . . . . . .
>   ‘Mrs Weedon, you’re still smoking, which affects the dose I have to prescribe you. If you’d give up your cigarettes – smokers metabolize Theophylline more quickly, so the cigarettes are not only worsening your emphysema, but actually affecting the ability of the drug to—’ 
>   ‘Don’ you shout at me! I’ve ’ad enough **of you**! I’ll report you! You’ve gave me the wrong fuckin’ pills! I wanna see someone else! I wanna see Dr Crawford!’
>   (The Casual Vacancy, by J. K. Rowling)

(1) They set up a routine cry **of injustice** at this.
(2) I’ve ’ad enough **of you**!

Can I understand that the two of-complements's *'injustice'* and *'you'* are the objects of ‘*set up a routine cry*’ (in 1) and ‘*have had enough*’ respecively (in 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it.

"of injustice" attaches to "cry", forming "cry of injustice" (a complaint).

"of you" attaches to "I've had enough", forming "I've had enough of you"— meaning that the speaker no longer wants to (in this case) do further business with whoever they're talking to.